# What would be the correct abstraction for Thing and Action?

Tags: ontology

In an hierargical ontology definition I'm stating that: `Artist <= Person <= Human <= Mamal <= Thing` or `Phone <= Product <= Thing`. I could also do the same for `Walking <= Moving <= Action`.

This creates a tree structure with at the top of the hierarchy: Things and Actions.

What single word can I use above Things and Actions to combine both?

So that I'll get:

- `Artist <= Person <= Human <= Mamal <= Thing <= ???`
- `Walking <= Moving <= Action <= ???`

Comment: A *thing* or *object* or [*entity*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity) " is something that exists as itself, as a subject or as an object, actually or potentially, concretely or abstractly, physically or not. It need not be of material existence." If we agree on this, it is hard to imagine a "common" term for *entity* and *action*: an *action* is not existing as itself (withou an agent).

Comment: Good point, that is exactly why I'm struggling with this.

Comment: I call it a pattern but it is wider than just thing and action, it also includes concepts, words, grammars, abilities, etc.

Comment: In Buddhist ontology the term would be dhamma or 'thing-event'. .

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, we can't know. What our minds comprehend is dependent on senses. Yes, it makes sense to say there are *things* existing without minds. This is the most useful way of thought. Action requires an agent? Well, atoms are agents then. However, I would generalize action to verbative (not a word) and ask if verbatives exist on themselves. Existence itself is a verbative as anything else which can be expressed as a verb (*to exist*).

Comment: And what about _concept_?

Comment: A useful specification may be whether the "word" should combine _only_ Things and Actions.

Answer (score 1):

Bertrand Rusell had somehow suggested that events would be the *a priori* elements of existence. In such case, a thing is an event on our mind, and so is an action or reaction. This, due to all things exist really in our mind (as Berkeley suggests).

The difference between *action* and *thing* in your example is just mental. Actions belong to the realm of ideas, and despite things seem to be different, they are the same: things are part of our mental experience. For an informatic system, both have an start-timestamp and end-timestamp, and exist the same way in our mind.

But instead of event, I would call them *ideas* or *entities*, clarifying that an idea is associated with a start, duration, end, and an idea represents a whole, (as it occurs in our mind):

```
Artist <= Person <= Human <= Mamal <= Thing <= Idea (or Entity)
Walking <= Moving <= Action <= Idea (or Entity)
```

Comment: Ideas exist in human minds, so... I don't think it's good idea to call them so.

Comment: On a system we're developing, they're called _entities_, following the same considerations. Right, we prefer not to call a dog or a crime an idea. You can use entities.

Comment: I like _entity_ it makes sense in this context.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could use,

Thing <= **Entity** or **Existence**

&

Action <= **State**

---

If you want to combine both, what about this?

The word 'Thing' can be anything--animate, inanimate, tangible and intangible.  If you examine all the words you used (in the first case), you will understand that the change is gradual. A sudden variation is not reasonable in the first case.  So, the last word 'Thing' cannot contain forms, ideas etc.

So, if you want a common factor to combine Things and Actions, you could use the following abstraction:

- Artist <= Person <= Human <= Mammal <= Thing <= **Form** <= **State**
- Walking <= Moving <= Action <= **State**